# How to make all numbers equal to one in a Series?

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

I have many outputs of one-dimensional Series expansions for which I am only interested in the general tending with the variable.

For example, I would like to be able to transform something like

```
3.4235 + (4.22-5.2342 I) a + 7.543 a^6 + O[a]^7
```

into just

```
1 + a + a^6 + O[a]^7
```

etc.

I have tried many things, including trying to collect the SeriesCoefficients and reassign them to 1, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Here's an example of an attempt that isn't yet working (note, if it did work as expected, I would still need to add a simple If[] to exclude assigning SeriesCoefficients or Chop@SeriesCoefficients that are 0 to 1).

```
 clear[test]; test = Series[1/(1 - b x), {x, 0, 4}];
 Do[test = ReplaceAll[test, SeriesCoefficient[test, s] -> 3], {s, 0, 4}];
 Print@test
```

Probably a much more efficient solution to this problem would be a more general rule that could be applied to the final output that simply checks the expression for "numbers" and makes them all 1. Surely there is a way to get mathematica to recognize numbers compared to symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule suggestion:

```
3.4235 + (4.22 - 5.2342 I) a + 7.543 a^6 + O[a]^7 /. _Rational|_Real|_Complex -> 1

(* Out: 1+a+a^6+O[a]^7 *)
```

This simple rule unfortunately cannot easily be extended to handle integer coefficients. However, Mr. Wizard's solution does that.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Look out for `Integer` coefficients. ;)

Comment: And rationals...

Comment: Sorry, I was being lazy. All of them in there now.

Comment: @Pickett: cleaner perhaps: `Replace[3/4 + (4.22 - 5.2342 I) a + 7.543 a^6 + O[a]^7, _?NumberQ -> 
  1, {2}]` - NVM - this does not do it.

Comment: Nope -- just caught that lol (I meant mine...)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very true, it seems it will take some work to include `Integer` due to it being used in the hidden representation of series data. I removed Integer in the meantime. rasher: I think beginners like rules the way I wrote it more.

Comment: @rasher and Pickett, I think there is a better approach; see my answer, please.

Comment: I chose to down-vote this.  (Sorry.)  The given method does not handle integer coefficients, as acknowledged.  I feel that this makes the method unsuitable as it will behave erratically.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Completely understandable. I've edited the answer so that it acknowledges the flaw plus now people can change their minds about the vote if they want to.

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html) of your expression:

```
expr = 3.4235 + (4.22 - 5.2342 I) a + 7.543 a^6 + O[a]^7;
InputForm[expr]
```

> ```
> SeriesData[a, 0, {3.4235, 4.22 - 5.2342*I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.543}, 0, 7, 1]
> ```

You want to set all the coefficients to one, so let's do that with [`Unitize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unitize.html):

```
MapAt[Unitize, expr, 3]
```

> ```
> 1 + a + a^6 + O[a]^7
> ```

Or, if you prefer, as a Rule:

```
expr /. c_List :> Unitize[c]
```

> ```
> 1 + a + a^6 + O[a]^7
> ```

Comment: Beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @rasher I need to still win a few of those races or I'll feel old. :o)

Comment: Your rule method is not working for me in the general context, but the
     /. _Rational|_Real|_Complex -> 1

rule from above is. Perhaps there is more at work, but just letting people know. The Pickett solution will hit everything but integer coefficients, I suppose. For me, exact integer coefficients are absurdly rare, but for other problems that might be a concern.

Comment: @Steve Please give me an example where it fails.  Also, if it is only the Rule method is there any reason not to use `MapAt`?  I feel the latter is a distinctly superior method and I am prepared to argue that case.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I can provide a simple example where it fails, but in my research problem neither the MapAt or Unitize rules seem to work when implemented in the same way as the other rule.

Comment: Actually, in the more general context, the series are all individual elements of a matrix which is ultimately wrapped in Manipulate (which manipulates the expansion order of the matrix, and indirectly determines the expansion order of the series in each matrix element, which is part of the research problem not yet understood). I think perhaps the "3" argument in your MapAt might need to be changed in a precise way to reach into the right place inside all the matrix elements.

Comment: Here's a concrete example that causes issues (multivariable series):

m= 2 x - (3.54 - 2.1 I) y^2 - x^7

MapAt[Unitize, Series[m, {x, 0, 3}], 3]

Comment: And another example (matrix of series):

m = {{1, 2 x - (3.54 - 2.1 I) y^2 - x^7},
   {x y + 3.24 x^2 y^3, 0}}

MapAt[Unitize, Series[m, {x, 0, 3}], 3]

These issues are a bit broader than my original question, I acknowledge now, definitely.

Comment: @Steve Alright, that gives me a better idea of what you are doing.  Please give me the desired output for each of those extended forms so that I don't mistake.  I shall update my answer to address these.

Comment: @Steve I am still waiting for your reply.

Comment: Desired output for the multivariable series:
-x^7 + x + y^2

Comment: Desired output for the matrix of series:
{{1, x - x^7 + y^2}, {x y + x^2 y^3, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

I like the solutions offered above. This my answer is only in order to have one more solution, though it is not as good as those above. If the `O[a]^7` term is not dear to you, there is also such a way:

```
expr = 3.4235 + (4.22 - 5.2342 I) a + 7.543 a^6 + O[a]^7;

        FromCoefficientRules[
         CoefficientRules[expr // Normal] /. ({u_} -> v_) -> ({u} -> 1), a]

    (*   1 + a + a^6  *)
```